# Move button to random position (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move a button to a random position on the click of another button. Here is the code in my viewcontroller.

```
@IBOutlet weak var samea: UIButton!

@IBAction func yup(sender: UIButton) {

    let buttonWidth = samea.frame.width
    let buttonHeight = samea.frame.height


    let viewWidth = samea.superview!.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = samea.superview!.bounds.height


    let xwidth = viewWidth - buttonWidth
    let yheight = viewHeight - buttonHeight


    let xoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xwidth)))
    let yoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(yheight)))


    samea.center.x = xoffset + buttonWidth / 2
    samea.center.y = yoffset + buttonHeight / 2

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
}
```

I simply created an outlet for the button I want to move and then an action for the button that moves it. When I run this, it crashes at launch with the Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you give us more of your error output? This isn't enough.

Comment: Here is an imgur link to the error : http://imgur.com/a/BFSfV

Comment: See what is in the box in the bottom left? We need to see that. That is where we will see the error output.

Comment: I'm sorry could you specify what box you are talking about? I

Comment: I'm fairly new to xcode

Comment: The box in the bottom left that in the image had the text terminating with uncaught NSException

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://imgur.com/a/39bZa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error you are getting is a NSUnkownKeyExcpetion. What I'm assuming happened is when you wired your view controller in your storyboard to your file something got messed up. Right click on your buttons and see if there are two references on any of them. If so delete one. You may also be missing an outlet for one of your buttons that it think it should have.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Forgot to remove a couple references. Thanks for the help, that solved it !